# Mysql Select Before Time on date specified date

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So I have table 'content' with structure like this :

```
con_id
con_showdate (Y-m-d)
con_showtime (H:i)
```

All I want to get is rows which `con_showdate` is passed or same as today, but if the `con_showdate` is today then get only rows where `con_showtime` is passed or same as recent time.

Rows :

```
    `'1', 2018-10-24', '17:00';`

    `'2', 2018-10-25', '11:00';`

    `'3', 2018-10-25', '17:00';`
```

while recent date is 2018-10-25 and time is 12:00.

I tried :
`SELECT * FROM content WHERE con_showdate <= CURRENT_DATE AND con_showtime <= CURRENT_TIME`;

The result is :

```
    `'2', 2018-10-25', '11:00';`
```

which is not showing all rows before today (row 1).

Thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select all old dates and compare time only if date equals today's date, using OR as

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE con_showdate < CURRENT_DATE OR ( con_showdate = CURRENT_DATE and con_showtime <= CURRENT_TIME) ;
```